# Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'. TS2339

Tags: typescript

I'm switching from JavaScript to TypeScript, everything was going okay until I entered in this situation.
I set my interface in this way:

```
interface StreamCreateProps {
  [title: string]: any 
};
```

My code is:

```
const validate = (formValues: any) => {
  const errors = {};

  if(!formValues.title) {
    errors.title = 'You must enter a title';
  };

  if(!formValues.description) {
    errors.description = 'You must enter a description';
  };

  return errors;
};
```

How can I type the errors.title and errors.description correctly?
The full error is: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Record` utility type:

```js
const errors: Record<string, string> = {};
errors.foo = 'okay';
```

---

When you declare a variable without specifying the type, you cause the TypeScript Compiler to infer its type for you. The compiler will choose a reasonably narrow type. A few examples:

```js
const foo = false // false
foo = true // ERROR
// `foo` is constant, so TS infers `false`, the only possible value. 

let foo = false // boolean
foo = true // OK
foo = 100 // ERROR
// Using `let` or `var` will result in `foo` being reassignable, 
//   so it could technically be anything; 
//   however, TS assumes a narrower type based on its initial value. 

// `foo` is constant, but it's properties are not, 
//   so, like with the previous row, `bar` is assignable to any boolean. 
const foo = { bar: false } // { bar: boolean; } 
foo.bar = true // OK
foo.bar = 100 // ERROR

// a `const` litteral declaration: 
//   foo and its subproperties should retain the narrowest possible type.
const foo = { bar: false } as const // { readonly bar: false; }
foo.bar = false // ERROR
```

So applied to your situation:

```
const foo = {} // {}
foo.bar = 'baz' // ERROR: Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{}'
```

`foo` is too narrow to accept additional properties. `Record<string, string>` is less restrictive: it ensures you retain something like `{ [key: string]: string }`. If you need to work with non-string values, you could widen it further: `Record<string, string | number>` or `Record<string, any>`.

[Examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAZnANhApgbhgen1Q2wFgAodLWAIyWM1xmcJhpBCrjAtElmD0A3mzgAnAFwNsMAL4EiImuKntOWbnlm9w0GABNhoydKxz4EGHz2sRYjfvDoAnsalpGWijv6oOw7XIUDgA6ZTF6AHJlAC9IhRgAOQB5AAUAUQBCb3JrWHtQMX0pACUsQv0AHmgxAEswAHMAGhga%20oaAPgCcCgKQIrDxKNjIvFZkgGkAQQBNIA)

Comment: Very well explained mate. Thanks lad!